# Writing a sample ABAC authorization policy using ALFA and XACML

Tags: authorization, access-control, xacml, alfa

I am new to XACML and am writing a policy using ALFA. The policy I am looking to write is to set a transfer limit in a bank for amount of $2000. If the amount to be transferred is more than that, then the operation should be denied.

How do I go about it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The use case you have is quite simple. I recommend you write it in English first and then in ALFA:

- A user can do the `action==transfer` on a resource of `type==bank account` if and only if the `amount transferred < the amount limit` (e.g. 2000 in your case) ==> **permit**
- all other cases ==> **deny**

In ALFA, the above policies become

```
namespace policies{
    attribute actionId{
        category = actionCat
        id = "actionId"
        type = string
    }

    attribute resourceType{
        category = resourceCat
        id = "resourceType"
        type = string
    }

    attribute amount{
        category = resourceCat
        id = "amount"
        type = double
    }
    /**
     * The limit could be a subject attribute in the case it's user-specific
     */
    attribute limit{
        category = subjectCat
        id = "limit"
        type = double
    }

    /* 
     * A user can do the `action==transfer` on a resource of `type==bank account` if and only if the `amount transferred 
     * < the amount limit` (e.g. 2000 in your case) ==> **permit**
     * 
     */
     policy transfer{
        target clause actionId == "transfer" and resourceType=="bank account"
        apply firstApplicable
        rule allow{
            condition amount <= limit
            permit
        }
        rule denyTransfer{
            deny
        }
     }
}
```